# Webform within Access Form

Tags: ms-access-2007, webbrowser-control

I am trying to incorporate a html menu within access form. How would I get the feedback (on what the user selected within the web page) from the webpage into Access. I am using Access 2007, MS WebBrowser component.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: As in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196461.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, however, it does not explain how I get what was clicked on the web page. Say I have 5 links in the webpage (not sure what should be the href for these links or onClick for these links); and when one of them are clicked, Access mainform known which once was clicked.

Comment: Why not? Are the items clicked not navigation items?

Comment: I've experimented with this only a very tiny bit. In my experiments I would just move some value to the Title of the HTML document and then you can read that title from within Access. However, I don't remember for sure right now how push the onClick event to the Access form. I gave up trying to use HTML documents within Access unless it was for something simple that didn't require the HTML document to "push" something back to Access.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to call the hosting form or initiate any activity on Access from within the WebBrowser.

However, there is one nifty trick which I use. After the document is loaded you can setAttribute of some element to the Access form. `htmlDoc.all.formDiv.setAttribute "outerForm", Me`

Then you can reference properties and methods of the form from within the WebBrowser.

```
document.all.formDiv.outerForm.Application.DoCmd.Close(2,"webForm")
```

**EDIT**:
Oddly, it seems that the reference remains null when as I add the `<META http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>` tag. Seemingly, the properties are more strict now, and setAttribute is expecting a string.

The next option is to pass the Access Form ('Me') to a variable in the WebBrowser. However it doesn't look like the global variables or functions are directly exposed.

This, though, can easily be overcome by adding a function to the prototype of HTMLBodyElement which passes its argument to a global variable, and can return any class as well.

In the html page you'd have this:

```
var frm = null;
HTMLBodyElement.prototype.setForm = function(f){frm = f}
```

From Access simply pass the reference down: `htmlDoc.document.body.setForm(Me)`.